# MongoDB: Correct way to chain 'find', 'update' and 'delete' with some processing in between

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using Mongoose v5 in a Node application.
I have documents stored like this :

```
productId: 12345,
personId: 09876
```

I am receiving a request containing a list of productID and a personID.
For each combo productId/personId already existing in my collection, there is nothing to do. For each combo not existing in the request but existing in collection, I should delete them from collection. And for those which are new, I should add them to my collection.

The first thing that comes to mind would be to:

- *find* all existing productId for this personId
- In JS create 2 arrays, one containing the documents to delete and one containing the documents to add
- *insertMany* with the list of documents to add
- *deleteMany* with the list of documents to delete

It feels painful. I checked *updateMany* but it can't delete the none existing data from the input list.

Is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Thank you